# Glassfish - Domain wise redirection to application

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, glassfish

I am running `Glassfish Server` on `Linux 6` for my `Oracle Apex` applications running on `Port 8080` and `8181(for https)`.

now, suppose my domain is mydomain.com,

and when I access

a.mydomain.com -> it should be redirected to application 1 (i.e a.mydomain.com:8080/apex/f?p=1)

b.mydomain.com -> it should be redirected to application 2 (i.e b.mydomain.com:8080/apex/f?p=2)

and so on...

if it is hard to figure out with Glassfish, I can also move to `Apache Tomcat` if required.

Any advice/idea would be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Glassfish, but you might try [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) inside your virtual host config

```
ProxyPass / http://a.mydomain.com:8080/apex/f?p=1
```

Similar for the `b.mydomain.com` domain.

---

If you really want a redirect, i.e. the browser's URL changes, use [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead

```
Redirect / http://a.mydomain.com:8080/apex/f?p=1
```

Comment: Thank's @Olaf for the hint, Will look about `ProxyPass`.